# undefined as falsey in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, undefined

Suppose that `flag` is an undefined variable. When running a script locally within a browser I can run IF statements like the following:

```
if(flag){
  //do stuff
}
```

This works fine in the browser. However in nodejs it throws an error saying that `flag` is undefined. Is undefined not considered falsey in nodejs?

Comment: NodeJS is just more strict about using variables which haven't been declared before,

Comment: Is the variable itself undeclared *(undefined)*, or the value of the variable is undefined ?

Comment: It seems strange. I wonder what sort of mistake the are trying to protect me from making by being strict in this sense.

Comment: The variable is undeclared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's *not* "fine" to do that in browsers. Chrome and Firefox throws the same error in their console.

In JavaScript, there are 2 types of undefined:

- The value `undefined`, when you do this:
  `var flag;`
- The undefined variable:
  `if (flag) { ... }`

The first is a falsey value, while the second is error (supposing that you never did declare it, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Node.js executes in mode similar to [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) for performance reasons. This means that you cannot use undeclared variables.

What you can do to get around this is check the type, and go off that. For instance:

```
if (typeof flag != 'undefined' && flag) {
    // do something
}
```

This will check the type, and only attempt to utilize the `flag` variable if it is not defined.